# R. Change object attribute with a function call

Tags: r, igraph

Let `g` be an `igraph` object. For instance, a simple one

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_graph(~A-B-C)
```

If I plot this graph several times, the layout may differ. I want to fixate it somehow, so I came up with this solution:

```
attr(g, "layout") <- layout.auto(g)
plot_flo <- function(graph, ...){
    plot(graph, layout = attr(graph, "layout"), ...)
}
```

Now if I plot the graph with `plot_flo` (flo is for 'fixed layout') layout remains the same. 
Now what I want to do is to shorten this line with setting an attribute to a single function call. I mean something like this: 
`update_layout(g)`.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I managed to build such a function:

```
update_layout <- function(x){
    name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    paste0(name, "$layout <<- layout_nicely(", name, ")") %>% 
    parse(text = .) %>% 
    eval()
}
```

Don't know how it deals with good R code principles, but it seems working.
Still, thank you @GaborCsardi for the tip, now there is no need of additional plot function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you want to do.. Do you want to have a callable function that does 'attr(g, "layout") <- layout.auto(g)'?

Comment: You cannot do this. In R you cannot change the value of a function argument. (Well, unless it is an environment, but it is not.)

Comment: Instead, add the layout to the graph itself: `g$layout <- layout_nicely(g)`. Then you can just plot it: `plot(g)` and it will always look the same.

Comment: Thank you, @Gabor. Didn't know about this feature with layout. But as for changing function arguments, I wouldn't agree. I actually managed to construct a needed function finally.

Comment: You don't have to agree with me, it is a fact. :) It is just not possible. Except for manually setting in `parent.frame()`, which is really-really bad.

Comment: "Except for manually setting in parent.frame()" -  Well, looks like it's exactly what i did :)